# How To Filter (Customize) PHP out put IN Ajax and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-autocomplete

I have a Field in MySQL table which contains Address like :

[image]

I am able to query this field from MySql by suing these two PHP files(Ajax-jQuery Autocomplete  Proccess)

> 1: GetAuto1.php

```
<?php
include("configPDO.php");
    $likeString = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';
    $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Address FROM Barangays WHERE Address LIKE :likeString");
    $STM->bindParam(':likeString', $likeString);
    $STM->execute();
    $STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
    $Category_array = array();
    foreach($STMrecords as $row)
     {
      $result = $row[0];
      array_push($Category_array, $result); 
     }
     $json = json_encode($Category_array);
     echo $json;          
?>
```

> 2- GetCategories.php

```
<?php
$hostname = 'fdbxxxxxxxxxx';
$username = 'xxxxxxxxta';
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxxata';
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=xxxxxxxxxa", $username, $password);
    $locale = $_GET['term'];
$sql = "SELECT Address FROM `Barangays` WHERE `Address` LIKE '%$locale'";
 $Product_array = array();
   foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        $result = $row[0];
  array_push($Product_array, $result);
        }
$json = json_encode($Product_array);
echo $json; 
?>
```

> and finally the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
          $.ajax({
               url: 'Get_Categories.php',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data){
                     $('#searchg').autocomplete(
                     {
                           source: data,
                           minLength: 1   
                     });
               }
          });  
});
```

this code perfectly works for me BUT I have a problem here!.As you notice the Valuse shows on the Text box auto complete like:

> Aqtanga, Qlmeria, Giliran, Brazile

Can you please help me to modify the code to outputs the result(Filter it) to be like

> **Aqtanga, Qlmeria, Giliran**

I mean to mask the last part of the string after "**, Brazile**" How ever inorder to send the address to google map I need to filter the first part of string as well. So for google map I should make it like:

> **Qlmeria, Giliran, Brazile**

I mean filtering the first part which is **Aqtanga,** . sorry it took so long! thanks for your time in advance

Comment: I also tried using echo substr($json,12); which didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different steps to do. First, you should override the _renderItem method, as follows.

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {

     var address = item.label;

     return $( "<li>" )
         .append( $( "<a>" ).html( address ) )
         .appendTo( ul );
}
```

to be put after

```
minlength:1,
```

this allows you to use different HTML for displaying the item. However, for your case, it allows you to modify the address as you please.

For example, if you want to delete the last "Brazile", you may do this:

```
var address = (item.label.split(",").pop()).join(",");
```

In fact, in dividing the address according to commas (,), I am eliminating the last occurrence (with pop()), and recreating the address (with Join()).